# Fake POST for $this->getRequest()->isPost()

Tags: magento-1.8

how to create a fake POST to bypass

```
    $_POST = array('blahblah'=>1);
    $_REQUEST = array('blahblah'=>1);

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        echo 'horray bypassed';
    }else
    { 
           echo ':(';
    }
```

and is not working

here the answer:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST';
/* by pass */

$this->getRequest()->isPost()
```

Comment: question not clear? where do you want to bypass? why do you want to bypass?

Comment: question updated, why? let say,..just wondering

Comment: I think you can not By pass this way

Comment: $_POST has not any relation with $this->getRequest()->isPost()

Comment: maybe i have to use CURL

Comment: Your question seems out of context. Can you describe, in relation to intended magento functionality, what you intend to do, then maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` were the `isPost()` method is found and you will see the method is as follows:

```
public function isPost()
{
    if ('POST' == $this->getMethod()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and `getMethod()` is:

```
public function getMethod()
{
    return $this->getServer('REQUEST_METHOD');
}
```

So `isPost()` doesn't look for the existence of data in the `$_POST` array to detect a POST request, it looks at the `$_SERVER` variable `REQUEST_METHOD`.

Comment: For me worked $this->getRequest()->getServer('REQUEST_METHOD'); Thanks!