# Magento 1.9 Create Custom Form and add Validation

Tags: custom, forms, form-validation

I would like to have a custom form with name, address and email fields. However, I am unsure how to achieve this using the proper magento way.

At the moment I have the following raw form in my cms page, which posts to a php file in the root of my magento:

```
<form action="/requestBrochure.php" id="brochureform" method="post">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li><label>Name</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="name" name="name" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Email</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="email" name="email" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Address Line 1</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="address_line_1" name="address_line_1" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Address Line 2</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="address_line_2" name="address_line_2" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Address Line 3</label><br>
        <input class="input-text" id="address_line_3" name="address_line_3" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>City</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="city" name="city" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Post Code</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="postcode" name="postcode" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Country</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="country" name="country" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>
    </ul><button class="form-button-alt" type="submit"><span>Submit Your Request</span></button>
</form>
```

The requestBrochure.php file:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$address_line_1 = $_POST["address_line_1"]; 
$address_line_2 = $_POST["address_line_2"]; 
$address_line_3 = $_POST["address_line_3"]; 
$postcode = $_POST["postcode"];     
$city = $_POST["city"]; 
$country = $_POST["country"];   



$to = "example@example.co.uk";
$subject = "example Brochure Request";
$body .= "<p>The following customer have requested new example brochure.</p>";
$body .= "<p>Name : " . $name . "<p>";
$body .= "<p>Email  : " . $email . "<p>";
$body .= "<p>Address Line 1 : " . $address_line_1 . "<p>";
$body .= "<p>Address Line 2 : " . $address_line_2 . "<p>";
$body .= "<p>Address Line 3 : " . $address_line_3 . "<p>";
$body .= "<p>City : " . $city . "<p>";
$body .= "<p>Post Code : " . $postcode . "<p>";
$body .= "<p>Country : " . $country . "<p>";

$body .= "<br /><p>Kind regards,</p><p>example Admin</p>";


$headers = "From: "."noreply@example.co.uk"."\r\n" .
"Reply-To: "."noreply@example.co.uk"."\r\n". "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n" .
 "X-Mailer: php";
 $sent=mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);





$to = $email;
$subject = "example Brochure Request";

$body = "<img src='/images/example_logo_email.jpg' >";
$body .= "
<p>Thank you for requesting our new catalogue, which will be posted out to you immediately.</p>
";
$headers = "From: "."noreply@example.co.uk"."\r\n" .
"Reply-To: "."noreply@example.co.uk"."\r\n". "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n" .
 "X-Mailer: php";
 $sent=mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

if ($sent) {


} else {

}


header('Location:  http://www.example.co.uk/thankyou' ) ;
```

This is a very simple way and is not the magento way. How can I do this in the correct manner?

I have also added the following external JS to my cms page:

```
 var customForm = new varienForm('brochureform',true);
```

via:

```
<reference name="head">
 <action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>js/formvalid.js</name>
 </action>
</reference>
```

But, no validation is occurring and the form is still posted. The external javascript is loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a module with below steps:

**Step 1**: Create **Vendor_Module.xml** under

> app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Vendor_Module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Vendor_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2**: Create **config.xml** under

> app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Vendor_Module>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Vendor_Module>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
       <routers>
          <brochure>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Vendor_Module</module>
                 <frontName>brochure</frontName>
              </args>
           </brochure>
       </routers>
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <vendor_module>
                    <file>brochure.xml</file>
                </vendor_module>                
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <module>
        <class>Vendor_Module_Helper</class>
      </module>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Step 3**: Create **IndexController.php** under

> app/code/local/Vendor/Module/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ($post){
            try {
                $name = $post["name"];
                $email = $post["email"];
                $address_line_1 = $post["address_line_1"]; 
                $address_line_2 = $post["address_line_2"]; 
                $address_line_3 = $post["address_line_3"]; 
                $postcode = $post["postcode"];     
                $city = $post["city"]; 
                $country = $post["country"];

                $to = "example@example.co.uk";
                $subject = "example Brochure Request";
                $body .= "<p>The following customer have requested new example brochure.</p>";
                $body .= "<p>Name : " . $name . "<p>";
                $body .= "<p>Email  : " . $email . "<p>";
                $body .= "<p>Address Line 1 : " . $address_line_1 . "<p>";
                $body .= "<p>Address Line 2 : " . $address_line_2 . "<p>";
                $body .= "<p>Address Line 3 : " . $address_line_3 . "<p>";
                $body .= "<p>City : " . $city . "<p>";
                $body .= "<p>Post Code : " . $postcode . "<p>";
                $body .= "<p>Country : " . $country . "<p>";

                $body .= "<br/><p>Kind regards,</p><p>example Admin</p>";

                $from = $email;

                $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
                $mail->setToName('Your Name');
                $mail->setToEmail($to);
                $mail->setBody('Mail Text / Mail Content');
                $mail->setSubject($subject);
                $mail->setFromEmail($from);
                $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
                $mail->setBodyHTML($body);  // your content or message

                $mail->send();

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.');
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later');
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4**: Create **Data.php** under

> app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**Step 5**: Create **brochure.xml** under

> app/design/frontend/your_package/theme/layout/brochure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <brochure_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="brochure.form" as="brochure_form" template="brochure/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </brochure_index_index>
</layout>
```

**Step 6**: Create **form.phtml** under

> app/design/frontend/your_package/theme/template/brochure/form.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('brochure/index/post'); ?>" id="brochureform" method="post">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li><label>Name</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="name" name="name" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Email</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="email" name="email" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Address Line 1</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="address_line_1" name="address_line_1" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Address Line 2</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="address_line_2" name="address_line_2" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Address Line 3</label><br>
        <input class="input-text" id="address_line_3" name="address_line_3" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>City</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="city" name="city" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Post Code</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="postcode" name="postcode" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>

        <li><label>Country</label><br>
        <input class="input-text required-entry" id="country" name="country" style="width: 250px;" type="text"></li>
    </ul><button class="form-button-alt" type="submit"><span>Submit Your Request</span></button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var brochureform = new VarienForm('brochureform', true);
    //]]>   
</script>
```

Now you can edit the **postAction** according to your requirement.

Comment: How do I then call this form?

Comment: Url will be http://www.example.com/brochure You can change the url from config.xml by changing the frontname.

Comment: What if I want to add this to an existing page? Like an cms page?

Comment: Trying your way site.co.k/brochure has a 404. Doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Flush the cache once.

Comment: I have done, I have flushed entire cache also.

Comment: Did you added all the files I have mentioned in my answer? I think you not created all the files as mentioned to the correct locations. Can you recheck the locations and file names. As it is working fine in my local system and it should work everywhere in magento 1.x

Comment: Sukumar, was an issue in config.xml. Fixed now. How can I add this form block to an existing cms page instead?

Comment: You can copy the form to your CMS page and change action url according to CMS page. It should work.

Comment: You can also call that form on CMS page by adding the code {{block type="core/template" template="brochure/form.phtml"}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80997/discussion-between-vaishal-patel-and-sukumar-gorai).

Comment: Last thing is the sender name is shown as magento how can I change this? I tried `$mail->setSenderName("no-reply");` but didn't work

Comment: Try $mail->setFromName("no-reply"); instead of yours.

Comment: @SukumarGorai Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/244255/57334 thanks

Comment: this is only for submitting process but after save table resource remains right?

Comment: @Magento2 Devloper yes correct

Answer (score 1):

With an extension it is totally achievable. But explaining how to do this in an extension is beyond this answer.

To briefly explain, I'd follow these steps:

1. Create an extension.
2. [Add a layout file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19513002/956255) in `config.xml`
3. [Create a router](https://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/) in the extension.
4. Tell the router to load and render the layout file: `$this->loadLayout(); $this->renderLayout();`
5. In the layout file, bound a `phtml` file to `PHP` class. I mean [create a block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4518644/956255).
6. Paste the html code to your `phtml` file. Of course there's a Magento way to create forms.
7. Create a post action in the controller. A method like `public function requestAction()`.
8. [Validate the request](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/36884/4276). It should be `POST` only.
9. Do whatever you have to do after form submission.

And for the validation javascript. You can either insert the code inside the phtml file (step 6.) or you can add a new block with the code inside the block with your html content.

It's NOT a complete answer. It just intends to put you on the right track.